# MySQL changes unordinary digits (ś,ć,ą,ę...) into '?' digit

Tags: mysql, utf

I have a problem while inserting data to ***MySQL*** Database.
In the beginning my *DB* couldn't insert data with unordinary digits, but I found a solution to type these *SQLs*:

```sql
SET NAMES 'utf8';
SET CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

After that, DB does not mark any error - inserting works 'almost' perfectly, but digits like `ę, ś, ć, ź etc` are automatically changed into `?` by *DB*.

I use **MySQL 5.6.23**

Does anyone know what to do?

In advance many thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

I came across this quite a few years ago. See if this helps.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-table.html

You need to assign a character set to your existing tables.

Comment: Tried `ALTER TABLE db.table CHARACTER SET utf32 COLLATE utf32_general_ci;` and nothing changed ;/

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow these steps:

1. Try to log to phpMyAdmin and then select the database from the list.
2. Then click the "Operations" from the top tabs.
3. Now in the Collation box, choose the new collation `utf8_general_ci` from the dropdown menu  and if it is already there then select `utf8_unicode_ci`.
4. Click Go and check again

Comment: I use HeidiSQL, which Options are rather minimized